# Escaping Shebang in grep

Tags: shell, escaping, character, shebang

in a shell script, i'm trying to find out if another file is a shell script. i'm doing that by grepping the shebang line. but my grep statement doesn't work:

```
if [[ $($(cat $file) | grep '^#! /bin' | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
then 
echo 'file is a script!'
else 
echo "no script"
fi
```

i always get the error `"bash: #!: command not found"`. i tried several things to escape the shebang but that didn't work.

maybe you can help me with that? :)

cheers,
narf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you change your condition to this:

```
if grep -q '^#! */bin' "$file"
```

The `-q` option to grep is useful in this case as it tells grep to produce no output, exiting successfully if the pattern is matched. This can be used with `if` directly; there's no need to wrap everything in a test `[[` (and especially no need for a useless use of `cat`).

I also modified your pattern slightly so that the space between `#!` and `/bin` is optional.

It's worth noting that this will produce false positives in cases where the match is on a different line of the file, or when another shebang is used. You could work around the first issue by piping `head -n 1` to grep, so that only the first line would be checked:

```
if head -n 1 "$file" | grep -q '^#! */bin'
```

If you are searching for a known list of shebangs, e.g. `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`, you could change the pattern to something like `^#! */bin/\(sh\|bash\)`.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. that worked for me :) but i'm still not sure why `grep -q '^#! */bin'` works in this context and not in my line of code. i'll still use yours as it is much easier, but i'd like to understand, why my code failed in the first place...